# Evolution of Android testing methods

Tags: android

I'm doing a research on Android testing methods and their evolution in time. Could someone point me in the right direction (recent articles, books) I'm finding a lot of material surfing blindly but it's hard to distinguish between obsolete methodologies and not.
What is the current state of the art in Android testing?

Comment: Means? You want to know detail knowledge that how to do android app testing?

Answer (score 2):

The really good source of information related not only about testing on Android platform but mobile testing in general is "[Hands-On Mobile App Testing" book](https://leanpub.com/mobiletesting) by Daniel Knott.

It'll give you a general idea on how to approach to mobile testing and which techniques to use. Moreover it has plenty of information regarding testing tools which are currently trending on the market.